# ¿Cómo medir y mejorar el performance materializando IQueryables utlilizando EF?

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Busco una forma, de ser posible integrada en el `IDE` de `Visual Studio`, de obtener métricas el performance al materializar `IQueryables` utilizando `EF` y de obtener directivas para mejorarlo.

Answer (score 2):

Tambien puedes formar y ejecutar tus queries en [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), el programa te muestra el tiempo de ejecucion, ademas te deja ver el codigo IL y la traduccion a SQL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar el **Sql Profiler** para analizar como se genera la consulta.

Si usas un Sql server Express podrias usar [expressprofiler](https://expressprofiler.codeplex.com/)

Con esto podrias ver la secuencia de consultas que genera la aplicacion, teniendo un trace de las mismas.

Despues podrias tomar la query que te interesa profundizar y ejecutarla desde el Sql Server Management Studio para analizar el [Plan de Ejecucion](https://www.mssqltips.com/tipImages2/1945_image001.png)

saludos